# Flex token order

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am having problem to declare the following tokens in flex: >, <, >=, <= >>,<<, >>=, <<=.

I declared like this: (flex)

```
ID          [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*

">"         {
                ultimo_token = ">";
                return BT_OP;
            }

"<"         {
                ultimo_token = "<";
                return LT_OP;
            }

"<<"        {
                ultimo_token = "<<";
                return ESQ_OP;
            }
">>"        {
                ultimo_token = "<<";
                return DIR_OP;
            }                               

"<="        {
                ultimo_token = "<=";
                return LE_OP;
            }

">="        {
                ultimo_token = ">=";
                    return GE_OP;
                }
">>="       {
                ultimo_token = ">>=";
                return DIR_ATRIBUICAO;
            }           

"<<="       {
                ultimo_token = "<<=";
                return ESQ_ATRIBUICAO;
                }

{ID}+       {
                ultimo_token = "IDENTIFICADOR ";
                ultimo_token += yytext;
                yylval.sval = new string(yytext) ;
                return IDENTIFICADOR;
            }
```

and in bison its not working here:

```
expressao_relacional
    : expressao_shift { $$ = $1; }
    | expressao_relacional LE_OP expressao_shift { $$ = new NOperacaoBinaria($1, Operador::LE_OP, $3, $1->linha); }
    | expressao_relacional GE_OP expressao_shift { $$ = new NOperacaoBinaria($1, Operador::GE_OP, $3, $1->linha); }
    | expressao_relacional LT_OP expressao_shift { $$ = new NOperacaoBinaria($1, Operador::LT_OP, $3, $1->linha); }
    | expressao_relacional BT_OP expressao_shift { $$ = new NOperacaoBinaria($1, Operador::BT_OP, $3, $1->linha); }
    ;
```

in the code example like this one: if(a > b). It ignores > and match instead of IF '(' expression ')' where expression -> identifier rule. But there is a b identifier so it report an error...

I wrote the test scanner with the -d option and it printed this:

```
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 434 ("if")
if
--accepting rule at line 274 ("(")
(
--accepting rule at line 478 ("a")
a
--accepting rule at line 484 (" >> ")
--accepting rule at line 478 ("b")
b
--accepting rule at line 280 (")")
)
--accepting rule at line 484 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 446 ("then")
then
--accepting rule at line 484 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 248 ("{")
{
--accepting rule at line 484 ("

")
--accepting rule at line 259 ("}")
}
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 484 ("
")
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--EOF (start condition 0)
```

code: if(a >>b) { }

<< is matching this rule:

```
[ <<EOF>>\0\t\v\r\n\f]+ ; /* eat up whitespace */
```

why?

...

thx rici...

Comment: You need to show a bit more of your grammar and/or scanner rules. (For example, what is the scanner rule for an identifier?) Also, does bison report any conflicts?

Comment: it does seems ok. for example if a replace ">" for "." and test a . b, it works. it's not working  >>, <<, >, < but its working >>=, <<=, >= and <=. Bison reports: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFICADOR, expecting ')'. code example: if (a >>b) { }. It seems like flex didnt returned "<<" so bison its trying to match if(a) but found b instead of )

Comment: Does flex give you any warnings? Have you tried building a debugging scanner using the `-d` option, which will print a message for every token recognized?

Comment: i wrote a test scanner and this code: if (a >> b) then { } and it printed: if, (, a, b, then, {, }.

Comment: Of course it is recognizing +1 as a token. Your numeric rule is `[+-]?0?{D}+`, which explicitly allows `+` as part of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<EOF>>` is not a character, it is a special flex rule. So you cannot put it inside `[...]` to make it part of a character class. When you try to do that, the letters `<`, `>`, `E`, `O` and `F` become part of the character class.

You hardly ever need a `<<EOF>>` rule, anyway and you certainly should not attempt to ignore it.

Remember that flex will use the *first* matching pattern in a scanner definition, when more than one pattern has the same longest match. So order matters. Unless you suppressed or ignored flex's warnings, it would have told you that your `"<"` and `"<<"` rules could never match, because they were overridden by the erroneous whitespace rules. It's always important to read and try to understand warnings (or at a minimum ask about what they mean, particularly when they seem relevant.)

From your comment about EOF matching the error pattern, I suspect that you are using an empty match to trigger an error condition. *Don't do that.* Your error (default) rule should be the last one in the definition, and it should match `.|\n` (or just `.` if you are certain that `\n` will always be matched by some rule.) That will catch any otherwise unrecognized single character, but will not be triggered by the end of file, because, as I said earlier, `<<EOF>>` is *not* a character.

Comment: @brlebtag: I tried it with flex (2.5.35) and it warned "duplrule.l:3: warning, rule cannot be matched." Did you suppress warnings by using `-w`? Or do you have a very old flex?

Comment: i guess it's old version. Makefile: lex.yy.c: lexico.l sintatico.tab.h
flex lexico.l